# Box cloud syncing with davfs2

Tags: dual-boot, sync, cloud, davfs2

I have set up dual boot on my computer:  I had Windows 7-32bit and added Ubuntu 14.04 -64bit.
(just this past Sunday, so I'm a total newbie)
A fundamental practice was the use of Box cloud.  I managed and suceeded to mount a Box folder with DavFS2.  I used the existing folder in the Windows C: partition so I would have one space on disk, where both OS would have the local image of the cloud.

At first glance all looked fine.  Now the questions:

1. Why do Nautilus and all instances of file displays (e.g. listings to
   select files in apps to open) take so long loading the directories? Nautilus sometimes crashed and I got system error reports ocasionally
2. Obviously sync does not work as I expected because while in Ubuntu
   files that I knew had been uploaded in the cloud in the meantime,
   came through and appeared locally (in their allocated folder, in the
   win partition.  However when booting back with Windows the files
   that had already been synced/downloaded and other ones that I had
   added to the folder while working in Ubuntu did not show up, until
   they were synced once againg by BoxSync under Windows!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BoxSync version 3 works flawlessly under PlayOnLinux / Wine

See the last post on [this thread on the PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-12812-2.html) forum

Answer (score 0):

It is clear to me now (almost) how this DavFS2 works (almost).  Had I only realized.. it was a lot of work, to get it running, and an overkill considering it doesn't provide syncing the way I expected :  the way the native BoxSync application does in Windows.
Also considering the time lags and the errors, it seemed unjustified to proceed with more involvement with this scheme to sync Box. I cancelled the loading and mounting.

**Alternatives:**

- A mount on demand of the remote Box DAV, works without any additions to Ubuntu, just mount from native Nautilus > Network .   [For complete instruction see this](https://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/03/mount-box-cloud-storage-in-ubuntu-12-04-11-10/)
  I use this 2 ways :  (a) access to the cloud in a file structure, yet no syncing or (b) acces the Win7 BoxCloud directory, which will sync next time in Windows, automatically.
  Neither a or b, perfect, both better for me now, less confusing plus resource economy and stablility.
- It has been suggested in very interesting articles, that git and git-annex apps can be used for a daemon, sync purpose.  Seems more elegant, more complete.  I have yet to try.  More info [here1](http://git-annex.branchable.com/tips/using_box.com_as_a_special_remote/).

Comment: More on alternative with Git and Git-Annex [here2](http://git-annex.branchable.com/special_remotes/) and [here3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUrQsK5ouSg)